# How to enable/disable custom meta-box in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I want to enable and disable custom meta-box on click of a button in my plugin. This button will be on the settings page of the plugin. This is what I've done so far:

```
function wpplugin_settings_page_markup()
{
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
        return;
    }

    ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php esc_html_e(get_admin_page_title()); ?></h1>
        <?php
        ?>
        <form method="post" action=""> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="postcb" name="postcheck" value="Post">
        <label id='postcbid' name="labelpostcheck" for='postcb'>
            Post
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn">
    </form> 
    </div>


<?php

    function cd_meta_box_add()
    {
        $multi_posts=array('post', 'page');
        foreach ($multi_posts as $multi_post) { 
            add_meta_box(
                'my-meta-box-id', //id
                'Custom Meta Box', //title
                'cd_meta_box_cb', //callback
                $multi_post, //post type
                'normal', //position
                'high' //priority
            );
        }

    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add');            

    function cd_meta_box_cb()
    {
        echo'<b> This is Custom meta box </b>';
    }

}
```

This code does not display the meta-box but I want the meta-box to be added only when that checkbox is checked, and removed when checkbox is not checked. Can anyone please help me achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code which saves this checkbox submission?

Comment: You mean I should save the state of this checkbox in database?

Comment: Yes that's right create your menu page using the link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/
Then save the post, page checkbox in option using add_option() and then show the metabox depending on what user has saved in option.

Comment: Okay got it, thank you!